# Bootstrap navbar collapse and visible part

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a theme with Bootstrap and I would like my top menu to have:
about, home, contact etc., and another icon for messages. ([you can check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQzzz.jpg))

But when the page is viewed on mobile I would like the menu to collapse as in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aveN.png)

But only the messages icon to be still visible.

Currently it is not, any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image icon with .visible-xs class example:

```
<img class="visible-xs" src="...">
```

Here is the link for more information:
[Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: Yes but is inside the divofthe collapse.

Comment: And if it is in different divs. So in mobile it will be below it and not side by side